# XmlReader ArgumentException: Specified type 'System.Guid' is not supported

Tags: c#, mono, xmlreader

I am trying to read an xml with an XmlReader, but I receive an exception on something that I didn't expect.

```
ArgumentException: Specified type 'System.Guid' is not supported.
System.Xml.XmlReader.ValueAs (System.String text, System.Type type, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementContentAs (System.Type type, IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver)
```

The exception was thrown in the following line of code:

```
propInfo.Value = _cReader.ReadElementContentAs(propInfo.PropertyType, null);
```

Where `propInfo` is a wrapper for a public property (getter-setter) that has to be serialized. In this line of code I try to read the value from xml and set it in the wrapper. I thought that a `System.Guid` would be supported, because there is also a `XmlConvert.ToGuid()` method.

What is a good way to serialize an xmlelement of a single type via this way? I cannot use `XmlSerializer` for complex reasons with Mono.

Comment: So... read/write as a string and use XmlConvert to shim between Guid / string...?

Comment: There are more types than only a Guid actually and I was hoping for a more general answer that I can use on other types as well. Even those that are not in `XmlConvert`.